# Upgrading cocos2d project to OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I have this code in a cocos2d 1.0 project which is a part of a tiny wings remake from here: https://github.com/haqu/tiny-wings

```
- (void) draw {

#ifdef DRAW_BOX2D_WORLD

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glPushMatrix();
glScalef(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), 1.0f);
world->DrawDebugData();
glPopMatrix();

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

#else

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _stripes.texture.name);

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, hillVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, hillTexCoords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nHillVertices);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

#endif
}
```

I have a hard time translating this to OpenGL ES 2.0. I find the documentation very vague.

What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

use this draw function instead of your above one.

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    self.world->DrawDebugData();    
    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

Also use GLES-Render.h and GLES-Render.m from Cocos2D 2.0